# Best Way to Handle Files Accidentally Omitted from Prior Checkin?

Tags: mercurial

What is the best way to handle the situation "oops, I forgot to include a couple of files in the previous check-in" . . . ?  Rather than follow it up with an additional check-in with the comment "Oops, forgot these files" . . . ?

Answer (score 2):

**None of these should be used if the mistaken commit has already been pushed or pulled anywhere; they rewrite history and will cause problems when it comes to publishing the rewritten commits.**

Both of these solutions assume you haven't made any intervening commits.

Depending on whether you're running a recent enough version of Mercurial:

```
hg add <missing files>
hg commit --amend
```

I'm not sure which version it was introduced in, offhand.

The pre-`amend` alternative is `rollback`:

```
hg rollback
hg add <missing files>
hg commit
```

Answer (score 0):

If using mercurial 2.2 or later you should probably use the amend flag `hg commit --amend`. From the help:

> The --amend flag can be used to amend the parent of the working directory with a new commit that contains the changes in the parent in addition to those currently reported by hg status, if there are any. The old commit is stored in a backup bundle in .hg/strip-backup (see hg help bundle and hg help unbundle on how to restore it).

Otherwise you can either use rollback (not recommended since you are rewriting history) `hg rollback`:

> This command should be used with care. There is only one level of rollback, and there is no way to undo a rollback. It will also restore the dirstate at the time of the last transaction, losing any dirstate changes since that time. This command does not alter the working directory.

Or use `hg backout`:

> Prepare a new changeset with the effect of REV undone in the current working directory.
>   If REV is the parent of the working directory, then this new changeset is committed automatically. Otherwise, hg needs to merge the changes and the merged result is left uncommitted.